# Disqus "unable to load" during Google "fetch and render"

Tags: seo, javascript, disqus

If you look carefully at the below image you can see the message "We were unable to load Disqus" ...

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: So, have you fixed that issue? I'm trying to fix the same on my site.

Comment: I just checked and this issue is not fixed, however Google is seeing my Disqus comments. I just searched for text from one of my comments and it came up in search. Read http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157

Answer (score 1):

Check _config.yml file

Change it from "www.sitename.com" to "http://www.sitename.com"

Source--- [here](http://www.fullcircles.ch/blog/2013/12/12/we-were-unable-to-load-disqus/)

Comment: Is that the octopress config.yml file? I don't have any config.yml file in my rails project